# where to store a jbuilder template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to use a jbuilder template.

Given the controller,

```
class Api::ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @review_request = ReviewRequest.new(review_request_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
    if @review_request.save
      render 'review_requests/review'
    else
      head :forbidden
    end
  end
end
```

and I have the jbuilder template stored at `app/views/review_requests/review.json.jbuilder`

```
json.review_request do
  json.(@review_request, :title,)
end
```

I'm getting a template note found error.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template review_requests/review with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/jd/Dropbox/application-code/antipattern/app/views"
  * "/Users/jd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
  * "/Users/jd/Dropbox/application-code/antipattern"
  * "/"
):
  app/controllers/api/reviews_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Any thoughts on either where the correct place to store this template is or why rails isn't finding the template i'm using (if the storage location happens to be ok)?

Comment: You need to use `respond_to` to respond to the `json` request.

Comment: @bronislav do you notice the `respond_to` already written in the controller? I don't think that is the case here unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @bronislav so actually, my error was that I wasn't making `.json` requests to the server, kind of an error on my part but your statement made me think about it so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jbuilder needs a json type web request, an html request to a rails server will cause the jbuilder template to not be rendered.